# Hexadecimal string representation of the iOS DeviceToken using hhx format

Tags: swift, string, hex, nsdata

I saw some solutions for the properly way to use the Device Token from [`application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622958-application?preferredLanguage=occ) but I couldn't understand the logic of it.

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

Can someone explain what `%02.2hhx` does?

Comment: It's the format specifier for the string. Here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: @Desdenova I see, so the `x` prints hexadecimal and the `hh` defines the length of each byte? Even so, I can't understand the precision field: `02.2`

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: The hh only defines what kind of input you have (1 byte character): Length modifier specifying that a following d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument.
The the 0 defines the leading zeros. The next 2 defines the width of the result and the last 2 the width  which is filled up with 0. E.g. 04.2 would give you "  01".

Comment: @AlexanderJährling, sorry, I don't understand how "0.42" part of the format string leads to "01". Can you share the documentation of what those numbers in that position mean?